# Fixing 'middleware not in use' error with passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, middleware

I have spent the better part of the last day and a half trying to figure this issue out, but I cannot seem to get passed it. I have looked at so many different places trying to find the answer, but none of their answers really addressed my specific issue.

I am trying to get npm passport to work. I have sample code from a separate tutorial that works. I have tried recreating it in my project but it's not working. When I try to log in, I get an error:

```
D:\OneDrive\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:46
if (!this._passport) { throw new Error('passport.initialize() middleware not in use'); }
                             ^

Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (D:\OneDrive\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:46:34)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (D:\OneDrive\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:253:13)
    at verified (D:\OneDrive\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)
    at D:\OneDrive\config\passport.js:20:20
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```

It says my issue is on `config\passport.js:20` but I really dont think that is the issue. It is copied exactly like it the tutorial. I think the issue is in the server.js, but I don't know what.

**passport.js**

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const {User} = require('../config/database')

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username' },
    (username, password, done) => {
        console.log('passport.use' ,{username, password});
        const loginName = username.toLowerCase()
        User.findOne().or([{loginName}, {email: loginName}]).then(user => {
            console.log('Authentacating User:', {username, password});
            if (user == null) {
                console.log('Failed to find username');
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect login name'})
            }
            if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) {
                console.log('Password was wrong');
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'})
            }
            console.log('Passed:', {user});
            return done(null, user)
        })
    }
))

module.exports = passport
```

**server.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') 
    require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const passport = require('./passport')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9057

const app = express()

/// EXPRESS ///
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())

/// ROUTES ///
require('../routes/html-routes')(app)
require('../routes/api-routes')(app)

/// HANDLEBARS ///
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({ defaultLayout: 'main' }))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

/// PASSPORT ///
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:' + PORT)
})
```

You can see all the code here on my [github](https://github.com/ToMakPo/FamilyTree)

Comment: In most frameworks your 'utility middlewares' need to be loaded before your 'regular routes'. Could that be the issue here, or does express always load routes last?

Comment: @Evert - I don't know but when I move routes down I have a different issue. `Error: Failed to serialize user into session`

Comment: Sounds like progress!

Comment: I figured that one out too and now I think it's working. Thank you for your help.